# Anaconda unicode error on command line startup on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got this error when running python from command line on Windows 10:

```
C:\Users\windows> python
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Failed calling sys.__interactivehook__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site.py", line 410, in register_readline
    readline.read_history_file(history)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\rlmain.py", line 165, in read_history_file
    self.mode._history.read_history_file(filename)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\lineeditor\history.py", line 82, in read_history_file
    for line in open(filename, 'r'):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 991: character maps to <undefined>
```

I have not changed anything about my python environment, I was just running some scripts that I've been working on for the last week. I honestly have no idea where this could be coming from; it seems to be an issue when python reads in its history. Updating python and conda did nothing. I found a very similar issue on a Chinese site [here](https://ask.hellobi.com/question/24842) but the solution is unhelpful.

At the moment, I cannot find any issues when continuing to run python or my scripts, but I don't want this to come back and bite me. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You have a history file that contain characters that cannot be decoded.  Remove the history file (POSIX: `~/.python_history`, on Windows it might be `%userprofile%/.python_history`) and see if that problem goes away.

Comment: taking away the history file is okay? I don't know a lot about python's behind-the-scenes

Comment: Yes, it's just whatever the user typed into the interactive console from previous sessions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As user [metatoaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2904896/metatoaster) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52049887/anaconda-unicode-error-on-command-line-startup-on-windows/56124666#comment91051182_52049887), the python history file contains bytes that cannot be decoded by your system's default encoding and may be deleted.  If the file contains commands that you want to keep or review you can take a backup first and try reviewing its contents in a text editor.

> You have a history file that contain characters that cannot be decoded. Remove the history file (POSIX: `~/.python_history`, on Windows it might be `%userprofile%/.python_history`) and see if that problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

in 'history.py' file, try to change "for line in open(filename, 'r'):" to "for line in open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8'):"

Comment: I don't think this adds anything as compared to the existing answers. It's probably preferable to delete the history file as suggested by others

Comment: Firstly, it's not recommended to edit module source files. Furthermore, an answer has already been accepted a while ago, and yours doesn't add anything. On top of that, "try doing..." is not a valid answer.

Comment: I support this answer and I have something to say to other commenters and downvoters. 1) Strictly speaking, the accepted answer only removes the cause of the problem; it does not solve the problem itself. Simply deleting the history file is cursory because some user may need it. Although making a copy works, it is a better solution to just keep the file while at the same time to have python interpreter work happily with Unicode characters in the file ...

Comment: 2) In contrast to the accepted answer, this answer solves the problem directly and to-the-point, so I think this is not only an acceptable answer, but also a correct answer that should've been accepted, which obviously adds something to the existing answers. ...

Comment: 3) The source modules are kept changing by developers, why can't other user? Python sources are not Bible or Constitute of a country. The purpose of changing sources is fix bugs and add new features. The addition of `encoding='utf-8'` successfully achieves this goal, so why can't we edit it? ...

Comment: 4) "try doing..." is a modest way of wording. If the answer is not valid simply because the answerer used a modest wording, that is ridiculous. I encountered the same problem and I repeated the answer just now. The addition of encoding successfully solved the problem -- Python interpreter started without any error, and all the history commands are read successfully, including the Unicode character in it. ...