# UnicodeDecodeError when running Python in Anaconda Prompt

Tags: python, anaconda

When I run `python` in Anaconda Prompt, I get the following error.
It does not disrupt my Python experience in any visible way, but it still unnerves me regardless.

Any idea on why this is happening?

I'm using 2019/03 version of Anaconda with Python 3.7.3

```
(base) C:\Users>python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 17:13:21) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Failed calling sys.__interactivehook__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site.py", line 439, in register_readline
    readline.read_history_file(history)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\rlmain.py", line 165, in read_history_file
    self.mode._history.read_history_file(filename)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\lineeditor\history.py", line 82, in read_history_file
    for line in open(filename, 'r'):
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 2990: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: check `0x81` in internet to see what char it is and in which encoding.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/52049887/5320906

Comment: Solved! Glad it was nothing serious...!

Answer (score 2):

`del %userprofile%\.python_history` deleted the Python history file with the character that could not be displayed for me and solved the issue.